# floor, ceil and round. ¿Cómo conseguir separar parte entera y decimal de un número?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

En el desarrollo de una estrategia, partiendo del siguiente DataFrame

```
from math import floor
import pandas as pd

{'Apple Inc.': {'2010-12-31': 9.83614444732666,
  '2012-12-26': 15.782343864440918,
  '2013-10-03': 15.157119750976562,
  '2015-09-17': 26.004854202270508,
  '2016-09-13': 25.16893768310547,
  '2018-12-28': 37.7598876953125,
  '2019-05-02': 50.767154693603516},
 'Entry/Exit Position': {'2010-12-31': 1.0,
  '2012-12-26': -1.0,
  '2013-10-03': 1.0,
  '2015-09-17': -1.0,
  '2016-09-18': 1.0,
  '2018-12-28': -1.0,
  '2019-05-02': 1.0},
 'Buy_price': {'2010-12-31': 9.83614444732666,
  '2012-12-26': 0.0,
  '2013-10-03': 15.157119750976562,
  '2015-09-17': 0.0,
  '2016-09-1': 25.16893768310547,
  '2018-12-28': 0.0,
  '2019-05-02': 50.767154693603516},
 'Sell_price': {'2010-12-31': 0.0,
  '2012-12-26': 15.782343864440918,
  '2013-10-03': 0.0,
  '2015-09-17': 26.004854202270508,
  '2016-09-13': 0.0,
  '2018-12-28': 37.7598876953125,
  '2019-05-02': 0.0},
 'Shares': {'2010-12-31': 0.0,
  '2012-12-26': 0.0,
  '2013-10-03': 0.0,
  '2015-09-17': 0.0,
  '2016-09-13': 0.0,
  '2018-12-28': 0.0,
  '2019-05-02': 0.0},
 'Available': {'2010-12-31': 0.0,
  '2012-12-26': 0.0,
  '2013-10-03': 0.0,
  '2015-09-17': 0.0,
  '2016-09-13': 0.0,
  '2018-12-28': 0.0,
  '2019-05-02': 0.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(df1)

if df['Entry/Exit Position'][0] == -1:
    lista_fechas = df[df['Entry/Exit Position'] == -1].index
        
    df.drop(lista_fechas[0], axis = 0, inplace = True)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)

df['Shares'][0] =  floor(df['Available'][0] / df['Buy_price'][0])                    
# Available money
df['Available'][0] = df['Available'][0] - (df['Shares'][0] * df['Buy_price'][0])   
    
for i in range (0, len(df)):        
    if df['Entry/Exit Position'][i] == 1:
        df['Shares'][i] =  floor(df['Available'][i-1] / df['Buy_price'][1])                    
        df['Available'][i] = df['Available'][i-1] - (df['Shares'][i] * df['Buy_price'][1])        
                             
    else:
        df['Shares'][i] = 0.0
        df['Available'][i] = df['Shares'][i-1] * df[value_name][i] + df['Available'][i-1]

df
```

Utilizo `floor` para conseguir que la compra de acciones con una cantidad determinada de dinero, sea un número entero.

Me devuelven el error

```
/tmp/ipykernel_2857/3629550615.py:61: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in double_scalars

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [40], line 61
     59 for i in range (0, len(df)):        
     60     if df['Entry/Exit Position'][i] == 1:
---> 61         df['Shares'][i] =  floor(df['Available'][i-1] / df['Buy_price'][1])                    
     62         df['Available'][i] = df['Available'][i-1] - (df['Shares'][i] * df['Buy_price'][1])        
     64     else:

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Si utilizo `ceil` obtengo el mismo error
​

Aunque es evidente viendo el DataFrame, que no hay valores NaN. realizo la siguiente comprobación que me lo confirma.

```
df.isnull().values.any()
```

Me devuelve `False`

La utilización de `round`, no satisface la condición de conseguir únicamente la parte entera del resultado de la operación.

¿Cómo puedo separar la parte entera de la parte decimal en el resultado de esta división, sin obtener después este error en la ejecución del script?. El script está en proceso de construcción, no está finalizado ni depurado, proceso que no puedo seguir hasta superar este error. Agradeceré sugerencias.

Comment: Hay unos 'available' y 'buy_price' iguales a cero, tal vez esto causa problemas al dividirlos y da NaN

Comment: Buen día, no es tu primera pregunta, recuerda que las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor incluye algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta para incluir  código ejecutable. El comportamiento esperado es obvio.

Comment: Creo que el problema está en la utilización de *floor*, pero aún no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Esto es correcto `df['Available'][i-1]`, lo digo por el `i-1`? ¿Existe la fia `i-1`?

Comment: Creo que sí, por que en el bucle for empiezo desde la fila 1. La fila 0 existe.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto cambiando el tipo de datos que devuelve la operación, utilizando np.array ().astype(float). El código completo, corregiso, queda así.

```
shares_number = np.array(floor(initial_capital / df['Buy_price'][0])).astype(float)


if df['Entry/Exit Position'][0] == -1:
    lista_fechas = df[df['Entry/Exit Position'] == -1].index
        
    df.drop(lista_fechas[0], axis = 0, inplace = True)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)

#df['Shares'][0] =  np.array(floor(initial_capital / df['Buy_price'][0])).astype(float) 
df['Shares'][0] = shares_number
# Available money
df['Available'][0] = initial_capital - (df['Shares'][0] * df['Buy_price'][0])   
    
for i in range (1, len(df)):        
    if df['Entry/Exit Position'][i] == 1:
        df['Shares'][i] =  np.array(floor(df['Available'][i-1] / df['Buy_price'][i])).astype(float)                    
        df['Available'][i] = df['Available'][i-1] - (df['Shares'][i] * df['Buy_price'][i])        
                             
    else:
        df['Shares'][i] = 0.0
        df['Available'][i] = df['Shares'][i-1] * df[value_name][i] + df['Available'][i-1]

df
```